# @each not updating computed sum value

Tags: ember.js, computed-properties

In a route with an array model, I need a couple of summary statistics available. These summary statistics need to be updated based on values typed into numeric input fields. I have attempted to implement this by setting these as computed properties using @each in a controller.

The properties (`creditTotal` and `costTotal`) compute on load, but fail to update when values are updated through the input fields. Unfortunately, they need to be updating, and I am at a loss how to make this happen.

Admittedly I am not a full time developer, so I am grateful for any assistance and insight you may be able to offer.

0640PST 03Jan2018: I also put this in a GitHub repo (https://github.com/knu2xs/arcgis-credit-calculator) to hopefully make it a little easier for anybody generous enough with their time to take a closer look at it.

Here are the relevant files, starting with the controller.

```
// ./app/controllers/index.js

import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  creditTotal: computed.sum('model.@each.creditCost', function(){
    return this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost');
  }),
  costTotal: computed.sum('model.@each.cost', function(){
    return this.get('model').mapBy('cost');
  })
});
```

Next, the model being referenced.

```
// ./app/models/credit-object.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

const _creditCost = 0.1;

export default DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  creditRate: DS.attr('number'),
  unitRate: DS.attr('number'),
  units: DS.attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 }),

  rate: computed('creditRate', 'unitRate', function(){
    return Number(this.get('creditRate')) / Number(this.get('unitRate'));
  }),
  creditCost: computed('rate', 'units', function(){
    return this.get('rate') * this.get('units');
  }),
  cost: computed('creditCost', function(){
    return this.get('creditCost') * _creditCost;
  }),
});
```

And the route.

```
// ./app/routes/index.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('credit-object');
  }
});
```

Finally, the template, so it hopefully makes some sense.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Credit Rate</th>
    <th scope="col">Unit Count</th>
    <th scope="col">Credit Count</th>
    <th scope="col">Cost</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each model as |creditObject|}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{creditObject.name}}</td>
      <td>{{creditObject.rate}}</td>
      <td>{{input type='number' value=creditObject.units}}</td>
      <td>{{format-floating-point creditObject.creditCost}}</td>
      <td>{{format-currency creditObject.cost}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  <tr class="table-primary">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{format-floating-point creditTotal}}</td>
    <td>{{format-currency costTotal}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try adding `'model.@each.creditCost'` in the computed properties (`computed.sum(here, '...', func...`). also please show the model hook of your route!

Comment: If I'm not wrong `computed.sum()` only accepts one argument, the dependent key. See [docs](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/methods/sum?anchor=sum).

Comment: @Jeff, I started with referencing the properties directly, as you mentioned, but these properties are also computed themselves, and I did not know if this was the root of the problem, so I was watching the actual property being changed. I actually removed the sum a few minutes ago to test, and interestingly, it shows the full array in the UI with the affected value changing when referencing `creditCost` and `cost`. Hence, the problem appears to be with `sum`, not with the computed property watching another computed property.

Comment: @ykaragol, this is where I started, and just now tried what appears to be the way it is intended to be implemented this way.
`this.get('model').sum('creditCost')`
Unfortunately, when doing this, I get an error, `TypeError: this.get(...).sum is not a function`. Am I on the right track? This method makes logical sense to me, but does not seem to be working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the solution through a *lot* of trial and error. While not exactly the most elegant, this is what eventually worked with Ember.js version 2.18.

```
creditArray: computed('model.@each.creditCost', function(){
  return this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost');
}),
creditTotal: computed.sum('creditArray')
```

I did stumble across an enhancement request discussing chaining of these types of functions so it could become something like this.

```
this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost').sum()
```

Currently this does not work, but I definitely hope it will in the future!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> creditArray: computed('model.@each.creditCost', function(){
>   return this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost');
> }),
> creditTotal: computed.sum('creditArray')
> ```
>
> I did stumble across an enhancement request discussing chaining of
>   these types of functions so it could become something like this.
>
> `this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost').sum()`
>
> Currently this does not work, but I definitely hope it will in the
>   future!

You have to differentiate between [computed property macros](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-property-macros) (e.g. computed.sum) and [native javascript array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) (e.g. mapBy).
The above is not possible because there is no `sum` function available in javascript, but it can be easily implemented with `reduce`.

```
this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost').reduce((res, val) => res + val)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
// ./app/controllers/index.js

import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  creditTotal: computed.sum('model.@each.{units}', function(){
    return this.get('model').mapBy('creditCost');
  }),
  costTotal: computed.sum('model.@each.{units}', function(){
    return this.get('model').mapBy('cost');
  })
});
```

With the '{' it should work just fine

Comment: I tried this, but it threw an error. As you can see in the discussion above, through a little more trial and error, it appears to be something I am doing wrong in how I am using the `sum` function, but have yet to figure it out exactly...